# What is the difference between := and += in kernel Makefiles?

Tags: makefile, linux-kernel, kernel

Are := and += same in Linux Kernel Makefiles and could be used interchangeably? If not, then what is the difference between the two ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As others say, `:=` is assignment.

But there's a fine difference between `:=` and `=`. In most cases it doesn't matter, but it may make a big difference.

`X = $(Y)` defines `X` as a recursive variable, which is something like a C preprocessor macro.
Whenever `X` is referenced, the value of `Y` will be used.
The expansion happens when `X` is expanded. So you can define `Y` after you've defined `X`, and it's OK.

`X := $(Y)` defines `X` as a simple variable. This is more like a C assignment.
Now, `Y` is expanded at the time of definition, so changing it later will do nothing.

`X += $(Y)` appends to `X`, but keeps its type.
If `X` was previously defined with `=`, `Y` will not be expanded immediately. Same if `X` was never defined.
If `X` was previously defined with `:=`, `Y` will be expanded immediately.

You can try this exmaple makefile:

```
X = 1

Y  = $(X)
Z := $(X)

X = 2

Y += $(X)
Z += $(X)

X = 3

test:
        @echo "Y = $(Y)"
        @echo "Z = $(Z)"
```

It prints

```
Y = 3 3
Z = 1 2
```

Comment: Yes, the distinction between `:=` and `=` is crucial to not going insane when trying to write/diagnose makefiles.

Answer (score 3):

:= is similar to =, i. e it is an assignment.

+= is a concatenation-and-assignment operator.

### Example:

```
VARIABLE := abc
# here VARIABLE is abc
VARIABLE := def
# VARIABLE is now def only!

VARIABLE_2 = abc
# VARIABLE_2 is now abc
VARIABLE_2 += def
# VARIABLE_2 is abc def
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. So can we also use = instead of := in Linux Kernel Makefiles ? Because I have never seen one. And I was thinking if there is a concept of _immediate assignment_ and _delayed assignment_ in kernel makefiles also ?

Comment: In the second case the variable becomes `abc def`, not `abcdef`.

Comment: Saying that `:=` is equivalent to `=` is misleading; there's a crucial difference.

Comment: Example given in answer by @ugoren clearly explains difference between **=** and **:=** .

Answer (score 0):

`:=` is assignment.  `+=` is concatenation. See [here.](http://www.linuxforu.com/2012/06/gnu-make-in-detail-for-beginners/)

Answer (score 0):

:= clears the previous value of the variable you are assigning to,whereas
+= adds (concatenates) to the variable

For eg, lets say CFLAGS has been set to -Wundef

If we do,

```
CFLAGS := -Wall
```

CFLAGS is set to '-Wall' now

If we do,

```
CFLAGS += -Wall
```

CFLAGS now becomes '-Wundef -Wall'

It is quite often used in Linux Makefiles.